# Destruction of Jerusalem Prophecy

Tags: luke, prophecy, historical-interpretation, jerusalem, olivet-discourse

In Luke 19:41 Jesus speaks about the destruction of ALL Jerusalem. In verse 44, Jesus says that "they will not leave one stone upon another". This prophecy sounds similar to others regarding the destruction of the temple but Jesus speaks about the city of Jerusalem. (I am emphasizing this point because the two prophecies have been confused before in another conversation).

Contrary to this stands the Western Wall in Jerusalem with stones still intact since the destruction of the city. I don't have the citation but I was also found that there was part of a wall from David's era still standing as well.

How do you reconcile Jesus' words with the historical record?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site. One aspect of asking Qs here is to show research behind the Q. It really is not enough to just make a claim (in this case, about some stones on the Western Wall in Jerusalem still being intact) without substantiating it. I have heard claims that none of the stones in the pre-A.D. 70 temple are in the Western Wall, but without a source to site and quote from, I would never base an answer on that. So, if you can do some research and come up with credible sources to quote, that would really help your Q.

Comment: In all my research I have not come across such a source. There was once a suggestion in an article that I read but that was it. It's hard to provide sources for a question that do not exist. Perhaps you could offer from the sources you've come across since you have heard claims. Thank you for wanting to support the question.

Answer (score 2):

A strong hint to the answer to this question is in previous verse:

> Luke 19:40 - “I tell you,” He answered, “if they remain silent, the
> very stones will cry out.”

We must make allowance in the Biblical language for idiom, metaphor and hyperbole.  Biblical language is very colorful and often uses metaphor and hyperbole to make a dramatic point.  Here are some other examples:

- Matt 19:24 - Again I tell you, it is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle than for a rich person to enter the kingdom of God.”
- Matt 7:3-5 - Why do you see the speck that is in your brother’s eye, but do not notice the log that is in your own eye? Or how can you say to your brother, ‘Let me take the speck out of your eye,’ when there is the log in your own eye? You hypocrite, first take the log out of your own eye, and then you will see clearly to take the speck out of your brother’s eye.
- Matt 18:9, “And if your eye causes you to sin, gouge it out and throw it away. It is better for you to enter life with one eye than to have two eyes and be thrown into the fire of hell.”

In Luke 19:44 (see also Mark 13:2, Matt 24:2, Luke 21:6) "not one stone left upon another" is simply Jewish idiom for complete ruin of the city.  After all, what use is a protective city-wall with large gaping holes that offer no real protection?

Answer (score 1):

**Destruction of Jerusalem** Thank you for your interest in a very important prophecy. There is probably a hyperbole involved here. However when read alongside the "whole counsel of Scripture" it makes good sense.  We especially refer to Matthew 24 where Jesus also said:

*Jesus left the TEMPLE and was walking away when the disciples came up to Him to call His attention to its buildings;*
*Do you see all these things, He asked? I tell you the truth, not one stone here will be left on another; every one will be thrown down!* (24:1-2)

The Temple was indeed destroyed to the max! The Wailing Wall you see today is just part of the retaining wall holding the whole Temple complex that covered dozens of acres (built by Herod). Read Flavius Josephus, WARS OF THE JEWS, for a blow by blow description of the conquest of Jerusalem by the iron-booted Roman Legions. He was an eye-witness.  The description Jesus foretold was just a drop in the bucket of the horrendous conflict and carnage wrought on the corrupt Jewish nation by the judgment of God.

Read also the dying words of Jesus as He made His way to the cross:

*A large number of people followed Him, including women who mourned and wailed for Him. Jesus turned and said to them, "Daughters of Jerusalem, do not weep for me; weep for yourselves and for your children.  For the time will come when you will say, 'Blessed are the barren women that never bore and the breasts that never nursed!' Then 'will they say to the mountains, Fall on us, and to the hills, cover us!*

Records show that **the whole city was demolished...** famine, cannibalism, unburied bodies with blood flowing in the gutters...the people killed by the millions, or sent into slavery so much that the price of slaves decreased in Rome...**eventually the Jews were forbidden to be in Jerusalem...the city was spread with salt so nothing would grow there!**

**Contradiction?** There is no contradiction in the scripture concerning the Destruction of Jerusalem (not just the Temple, but all of Judea was conquered for 3 and 1/2 years). Jesus could have used more hyperbole, and not been overly-exaggerating!

I recommend you read Ray Grant's TIMES,THEY ARE A'CHANGING, and Marcellus Kik's MATTHEW TWENTY-FOUR., for verse by verse exposition, along with Josephus's book. Keep studying the Bible. It's good for the soul.

{Much later, Emperor Julian the Apostate leveled the Mount Calvary, (Golgotha) flat to the ground too, to keep pilgrims frim coming there.}

Comment: This is the exact perspective I want to avoid. Instead of focusing on the main prophecy which I stated you have shifted to the temple prophecy. The "whole counsel of scripture" includes its parts. Please answer the question that I wrote first.

Comment: @user57385-Verse 41 stated that Jesus saw Jerusalem _and wept over it_, and didn't mention "destruction".  Verse 43 refers to the besieging of the city. Notice that this paragraph is possibly a short summary of His speech, and that in verse 44 the _not leaving a stone on another_ was His reference to the main part of Jerusalem: the Temple!  FYI, the walls you see today in Jerusalem are not Herod's; they were built by the Crusaders in the Middle Ages...and some built by the Muslim invaders. "The famous EASTERN GATE you see today sits upon the buried old gate under the ground.

Comment: I can see what you're saying about Luke 19:44, that it's really part of the Olivet discourse given in Matthew and Mark. That is a different thought I will have to give more attention to. Would you please provide sources for the case that the wall seen today is from the crusaders and invaders? I have not come across that claim except that these have built upon the remaining wall established by Herod.

Comment: @user57385-For a beautiful graphical presentation of our topic consult, WILIPEDIA, The Western Wall, section dealing with the "Muslim to Mamluk era" 638-1517, and "Ottoman era" 1517-1917.  The wall around the whole city you see today is also built by the Ottomans!  To solve confusion, note that the NIV mentioned "buildings" that Jesus would say are  to be torn down, not necessarily the foundations upon which they are built (retaining walls, etc.)

Comment: @user57385-For a beautiful explanation with pictures of the building of walls by the Muslims, et al., see Wikipedia, "the Western Wall", sections 'Muslim to Mamluk' 638-1517 A.D., 'Ottoman' 1517-1917. Notice that the NIV mentions "buildings" in verse 1. This may be a broader intent than just _the_ Temple itself.